# Prevent drawing beyond canvas with SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

Is there way to prevent drawing of parts of objects, like bitmaps or paths, which go beyond the borders of `Canvas` in `SurfaceView`?

When I gradually scale an object beyond the `Canvas`' size, especially with blurred paint, it all slows down to a stand still and I have to wait few seconds to get the control back -- it is not responsive. I scale an object by moving my finger over the screen; if I do it too fast and scale it up, then it really slows down drawing.

I did not have the same problem when using just ordinary `View` canvas, so don't know what is slowing it down. It's as though `SurfaceView` responds too fast and then gets congested.

So one idea to improve this, is to prevent drawing outside canvas, but not sure if `SurfaceView` has such clipping options.

Answer (score 1):

One solution perhaps is by using one of the `Canvas` `.drawBitmap` methods that accepts a source `Rect` / `RectF` argument, so that only the visible portion of the `Bitmap` is rendered. I've just done this on my own project to speed up `SurfaceView` performance where I have several `Bitmaps` that are sometimes only partially in view.

Comment: Yes, I can use this with bitmaps, but at the moment it is drawing a Path bigger than the canvas that is a problem.

Comment: I solved this , here is my answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54345823/how-do-i-stop-the-object-from-going-outside-the-screen/63450447#63450447

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if canvas would actually draw things beyond the dimensions, that wouldn't be a smart thing to do. Still, you can use `clipRect()` to define a clip region.

Are you applying filters like blur per frame ? that might be pretty expensive.

Also, are you triggering draw calls on touch event ? Touch events are generated very quickly and will flood the rendering thread. You might want to pick up events at a slower rate: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/Oe6k1_bm38o

Comment: Yes, the blur really slows it down, especially when the path shape is bigger than the screen. clipRect() has no effect. I tried to flag the begging and the end of the onDraw() so that inbetween the touch events are ignored, but does not help either; like the drawing has been passed to the hardware and that is where it slows down.

Comment: i solved this , here is my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54345823/how-do-i-stop-the-object-from-going-outside-the-screen/63450447#63450447

Answer (score 0):

When you put the SurfaceView on the layout of your activity, you can use the padding attributes like:

```
android:paddingLeft="20dp"
android:paddingTop="20dp"
android:paddingRight="20dp"
android:paddingBottom="20dp"
```

It works like this:

[image: Padding depiction]

To draw your canvas you can draw dinamically the borders with:

```
canvas.drawLine(1,1,canvas.getWidth()-1,1);  //Top border
canvas.drawLine(1,1,1,canvas.getHeight()-1);  //Left border
canvas.drawLine(1,canvas.getHeight()-1,canvas.getWidth()-1,canvas.getHeight()-1);  //Bottom border
canvas.drawLine(canvas.getWidth()-1,1,canvas.getWidth()-1,canvas.getHeight()-1);  //Right border
```